# Create new binary column based off of join in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

My situation is I have two spark data frames, `dfPopulation` and `dfSubpopulation`.

`dfSubpopulation` is just that, a subpopulation of `dfPopulation`.

I would like a clean way to create a new column in `dfPopulation` that is binary of whether the `dfSubpopulation` key was in the `dfPopulation` key. E.g. what I want is to create the new DataFrame `dfPopulationNew`:

```
dfPopulation =  X  Y  key
                1  2  A
                2  2  A
                3  2  B
                4  2  C
                5  3  C

dfSubpopulation =  X  Y  key
                   1  2  A
                   3  2  B
                   4  2  C


dfPopulationNew =  X  Y  key inSubpopulation
                   1  2  A  1
                   2  2  A  0
                   3  2  B  1
                   4  2  C  1
                   5  3  C  0
```

I know this could be down fairly simply with a SQL statement, however given that a lot of Sparks optimization is now using the DataFrame construct, I would like to utilize that.

Comment: DataFrames support joins. There are some examples [in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset). Remember that `DataFrame` is now an alias for `Dataset[Row]`.

Comment: SparkSQL compiles to the exact same execution plan as a Dataset operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SparkSQL compared to DataFrame operations should make no difference from a performance perspective, the execution plan is the same. That said, here is one way to do it using a `join`

```
val dfPopulationNew = dfPopulation.join(
    dfSubpopulation.withColumn("inSubpopulation", lit(1)),
    Seq("X", "Y", "key"), 
    "left_outer")
  .na.fill(0, Seq("inSubpopulation"))
```

Comment: I guess left join should be sufficient :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: I believe left_oter should be the same as left here. Correct me if I'm wrong :)